# Disc Not Ejected Properly… over and over

Tags: macos, external-disk

Since I neither eject nor turn off any external drives overnight, I find it odd that most mornings I get a stack of these notifications.

I have 4 external LaCie drives permanently running. Is this related to a specific drive? If I eject drives, this occurs less frequently. A few of the drives are 4 to 6 years old.

Mac Studio, Ventura 13.3.1

Comment: Does your Mac go to sleep/power save overnight?  Can you check/post your power settings?

Comment: There's actually a pretty good guide [here](https://iboysoft.com/howto/disk-not-ejected-properly-mac.html). I think it can help you troubleshoot the issue or at least find the culprit.

Comment: Spinning disks two or more years old, especially kept running continuously, are always suspect, unless you are using Enterprise class drives.